# Meteor accounts Twitter not working when deployed (Passenger/Nginx)

Tags: nginx, meteor, passenger, twitter-oauth, meteor-accounts

**Introduction**

I've developed and tested app in Meteor, everything is great until I upload it to the server.

I use *Linode* and got my *IT admin get Phusion Passenger* with *Nginx*. So first I upload the app to given folder, start Passenger (or Meteor for that matter) - go to the `IP address :3000` in my browser and it looks great.

**Except** for when I want to log in with Twitter, my pop up based anuthentication shows `web page not available`

**Question**

Do I need to install these dependencies manually? And if so, how? Or is it something else?

Comment: Is your `ROOT_URL` correct? What is the URL of the page that shows `web page not available`? I'm hoping its not `localhost`?

Comment: Ah! That was my nemesis my friend, thanks a lot for your comment, I was looking everywhere else but there. I'd be pulling my hair probably for much longer if not for you. Thanks!